# Can you make two versions of an interface, one with all optional and one with all required fields, while staying DRY?

Tags: typescript, interface, dry

I have an interface called `IPreferences`. It looks like this:

```
export interface IPreferences { 
    genres: Genres[],
    singers: Singer[],
    volume: number
}
```

Since I allow the user to update his preferences and only update one or more fields, I created an interface `IPreferenceUpdateRequest` that looks like

```
export interface IPreferencesUpdateRequest { 
    genres?: Genres[],
    singers?: Singer[],
    volume?: number
}
```

But this is bad because I now have two nearly identical interfaces.

Is there anyway for me to do this but stay [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  Use `Partial<IPreferences>`.  The `Partial<T>` type defined in the [TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.6.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1317) is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) that maps all the properties of `T` to optional versions:

```
export type IPreferencesUpdateRequest = Partial<IPreferences>
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Wow that's awesome. Didn't realize this use case was commmon enough to create a type in the standard library. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes the `Partial<T>` type defined in typescript allows you to this in e very DRY way:

```
export type IPreferencesUpdateRequest  = Partial<IPreferences>;
```